# Unit Test Method That Calls Async Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nunit, moq

I have code like this

```
public void Foo(...) 
{ 
   ...
   FooAsync(...);
   ...
}

private async void FooAsync(...)
{
   await Task.Run(() => Process(...));
}

private void Process(...)
{
   // slow process
}
```

I want to unit test Foo, and one of the things I want to test is that some method is called on some object (that I have access to) within the Process method.  The problem is that the Process method gets called after the check is made in the unit test.  How do I test this so that it behaves more synchronously?

Comment: Which testing framework are you using?

Comment: For starters, you should change the return type of FooAsync to Task. Try to avoid using async void https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell Nunit

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Also show what you have tried so far and identify the current and desired behavior

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test an async method with NUnit, eventually with another framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191831/how-do-i-test-an-async-method-with-nunit-eventually-with-another-framework)

Comment: @SachinKainth as an aside. From a design perspective, Foo is a misleading method. It is declared as a synchronous method that deceives you by calling an async method.

Comment: @Nkosi I cannot change the signature of Foo.

Comment: @SachinKainth, can you change the signature of any of those methods?

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, all except Foo.

Comment: @SachinKainth then abstract the `FooAsync` out into a dependency that properly implements the async members and unit test the implementation of extracted functionality. Make FooAsyn and Process proper async methods

Comment: `I cannot change the signature of Foo` - well, that's a problem, because `Foo` is where the problem is.